# CSS Font Groups

Tags: css

Can I group font's in my CSS file like this:

```
@font-group {
    font-family: custom-group;
    fonts: custom_font1, custom_font2, fallback1, fallback2;
}
```

At the moment, I've copied `font-family: custom_font1, custom_font2, fal...` onto many element's which is a pain to maintain and also bugs me how bad practice it is.

Comment: With classic css you can't combine. You are using less or sass/scss?

Comment: Why you want to create group of fonts? however you can apply only one font once

Comment: Nope :( ... should I?

Comment: @HidaytRahman a unified font across the page, aswell as unifed fallbacks, instead of a mess of random fonts.

Comment: The solution seems to be to add multiple @font-face rules

Comment: That is what I've currently done... `At the moment, I've copied font-family: custom_font1, custom_font2, fal... onto many element's which is a pain to maintain and also bugs me how bad practice it is` repeated code is disastrous, if I want to now tweak this list, I'll have to MANUALLY search through all my css files for usages.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can. However, with SCSS, you can use `@extend` feature to do this, which will only output a list of selectors that use this font.

```
%fonts {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.abc {
  @extend %fonts;
}

.xyz {
  @extend %fonts;
}
```

Check out this example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zpoxap

The output of the CSS is:

```
.abc, .xyz {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The `%fonts` is what's called a silent *class* or *placeholder*. It is only output if it is used. Placeholder's get a lot of criticism, because if you nest selectors, it can get very bloated in your output. I feel this example is a good use-case.

With regard to `@font-face`, you only need give it a name, like *"GT-Pressura"* and then it will become available throughout your CSS under that name.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "GT-Pressura";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src:
  url("../fonts/GT-Pressura-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("../fonts/GT-Pressura-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/GT-Pressura-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../fonts/GT-Pressura-Regular.svg#GT-Pressura") format("svg")
}
```

Then you can simply do what I have shown above in SCSS:

```
%fonts {
  font-family: "GT-Pressura", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.abc {
  @extend %fonts;
}
```

If you are not using SCSS, I recommend it because it's easy to port an existing CSS codebase to use it, as any valid CSS file is also valid SCSS. You could run everything through SCSS and only patch in the bits you need.

**Extra special bonus addition:**

If you do end up using SCSS, I very much recommend a SASS mixin library like [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) which makes writing `@font-face` rules that little bit nicer.

For example, you can simply do:

```
@include font-face("GT-Pressura", "../fonts/GT-Pressura-Regular", $file-formats: eot woff ttf svg);
```

Which is exactly what I use to output the above.

Comment: This seems like a cool feature; however, is it work reworking my application to add a few fonts to some elements

Comment: Could I not do: `@font-face { font-family: group; src: list, of, fonts }` Wouldn't that use the first supported font.

Comment: I made an edit to explain @font-face usage. See if that helps? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: I meant, instead of different font/extension types, use different font's -  wouldn't it have the same affect